# How to build simple OpenCV program

Tags: c++, opencv, g++

I am trying to build the program at http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html after installing OpenCV on my machine. I try to compile it using `g++ display_image.cpp -o DisplayImage` but I get the following error:

```
display_image.cpp:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
```

I think this has to do with how I'm compiling the program (some unresolved reference to opencv2) but I don't know how to resolve it. I'm using Ubuntu 13.04. Thanks!

Edit: I realize this is similar to [OpenCV 2.3 Compiling Issue - Undefined Refence - Ubuntu 11.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816607/opencv-2-3-compiling-issue-undefined-refence-ubuntu-11-10) but I don't really understand the use of  `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` and how to avoid it

Comment: looks like you forget to link with OpenCV lib with a -l or -L....

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV 2.3 Compiling Issue - Undefined Refence - Ubuntu 11.10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816607/opencv-2-3-compiling-issue-undefined-refence-ubuntu-11-10)

Comment: You can't avoid the use of pkg-config...

Comment: `pkg-config [package] --cflags --libs` returns the compiler flags and libraries that you need to add to gcc command in order to use `[package]` in your computer. You can avoid the use if you already know the output of that command and use it directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a linker error because you didn't specify OpenCV on your GCC command line

Follow that tutorial (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CompileOpenCVUsingLinux) link your sample with OpenCV