# CMake error configuring opencv

Tags: opencv, cmake

I have been trying to work with the flandmark code for facial detection. in order to compile the libraries, I need to run CMAKE.gui.exe. However I keep getting the same error and no one seems to have an idea how to get around it. I would really appreciate if please someone could help.

```
Error:
Cmake Warning at /OpenCV2.3/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake:153(message):

Found OpenCV 2.4.3 Windows Super Pack but it has not binaries compatible with your configuration.

You should manually point Cmake variable OpenCV_DIR to your build of OpenCV library.
Call Stack(most recent call first):

CMakeLists.txt:2(find_package)

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2(find_package):


Found package configuration file:

/OpenCV2.3/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake
```

but it set OPENCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be 
NOT FOUND

Comment: Well, the problem is exactly what it says: Your binaries are not compatible with the selected configuration. You need to download the correct set of OpenCV binaries for your compiler.

Comment: There is also a discrepancy: "Found OpenCV 2.4.3 Windows Super Pack" vs. "/OpenCV2.3/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake". Look at the different versions. Something looks broken there, too.

Comment: Please fix the title and the tags. It's not CMake that is not compiling, it's probably openCV.

Comment: If you had this problem when working with Android projects, take care of your `minSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 3):

**Just delete CMake cache.**

I've had more or less the same problem, posted & answered a question myself.

Check it at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36622706/3292304 for the whole problem if you want. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327197/opencv-is-considered-to-be-not-found/45892347#45892347)

It happened in my case since I had already installed another version of OpenCV.

I hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

Something weird is going on with the cmake configuration files.

For me the problem was solved by simply setting OPENCV_FOUND to TRUE and OpenCV_FOUND to TRUE.

Also I had to set OpenCV_DIR to /usr/local/share/OpenCV.

Comment: Setting OpenCV_DIR should have been enough. Did you get the same compatibility warning? I am not sure this is answering the same question.

Comment: Not a great idea to hack around a broken installation / configuration. This will come back to you sooner than you might think.

Comment: Setting OpenCV_DIR wasn't enough. Now it's working, before changing OpenCV_FOUND it wasn't working. Of course hacking around a broken installation is a bad idea, but I've tried all other suggested alternatives. If you've got a better alternative then please tell me.

Comment: When this happens to me I locate and read the CMake script for the finder to determine why it can not find the library it is looking for. My goal is to determine if the script has a bug (that needs reporting) or if it is a some type of problem that is specific to my installation. If necessary I debug the CMake script sometimes by inserting message( STATUS ${SomeCmakeVariable}) commands to look at some CMake variables.

Comment: Where are you supposed to set this and how?