# "OpenCV" is considered to be NOT FOUND

Tags: cmake, cvblobslib

Linux Flavor: Debian (Crunch Bang)

Problem Occurred: When attempting to build cvblobs with the following command

```
cd ~/cvblob
cmake .
```

Error:

```
CMake Error at cvBlob/CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package):
 Found package configuration file:

/usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake

but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be
NOT FOUND.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Could be that the installed version is too old. The version decision is made by the config file of the project to search for. Does cvblob request a specific opencv version in the find_package call?

Comment: If you had this problem when working with Android projects, take care of your `minSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 5):

Well I met a similar problem when I was going with some other open source face detection modules rather than cvblobs. 
Actually you will find that before these lines of error-info, there are:

```
CMake Warning at /usr/local/opencv-2.4.13/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake:163 (message):
  Found OpenCV Windows Pack but it has not binaries compatible with your configuration.

  You should manually point CMake variable OpenCV_DIR to your build of OpenCV library.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:57 (find_package)


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:57 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/local/opencv-2.4.13/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake

but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be NOT FOUND.
```

So you may notice that it asks you to manually point out the directory of you build version of OpenCV library.
For me, my source codes are at

> /usr/local/opencv-2.4.13/

but I make and install my release build of OpenCV at

> /usr/local/opencv-2.4.13/release/

so I use:
`cmake -D OpenCV_DIR=/usr/local/opencv-2.4.13/release/ ..`
and everything works:)

Comment: 0

Thanks! I had a similar mistake. I appended 'build' after the source directory. After I removed 'build' from the path, it worked.

Answer (score 4):

When I compile a program that use OpenCV lib, vision 2.4.8, occurs the similar error, when I point manually Opencv_DIR path to opencv/build ,visio 3.1.0, error occurred like you.

Then I point `Opencv_DIR` path to `opencv/build` whose vision is same to the program used.  It works.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason could be the another OpenCV package in another path, that you had installed before. In my case, I had already installed OpenCV for Python in `Anaconda` package, and the CMake always wanted to refer me to that package.

I simply added:

```
set(OpenCV_FOUND 1)
```

to my `CMakeList.txt` file, this command simply override the other package you may had installed. The final version of CMakeList file which is working for me would be this:

```
set( OpenCV_FOUND 1 )
find_package(OpenCV 2.4.13 REQUIRED PATHS "C:/opencv")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(OpenCV_Test ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

**Note:**

1- I am using the `CMakeList.txt` file for Clion IDE

2- I am using it under windows. Probably you may set the relevant path if you use other OS

3- You need also change the OpenCV version if you use other version

Answer (score 0):

the "set(OpenCV_FOUND 1) in CMakeLists.txt file" answer did not work for me, so instead:
**I changed the value of OpenCV_FOUND to TRUE directly on the "/opencv/build/OpenCVConfig.cmake" file**

[/opencv/build directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B4r8.png)

[openCV_FOUND value is False](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvASM.png)

[openCV_FOUND value is set to True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7ife.png)

Comment: Please provide textual information as text, at least in addition to pictures of text, because   
 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557