# how to include OpenCV's cv::VideoWriter when using vcpkg?

Tags: opencv, cmake, linker, vcpkg

I'm using vcpkg to install OpenCV4 on Windows.  But when I try to link my application, one of the OpenCV classes I'm using is giving me trouble:

```
2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl cv::VideoWriter::VideoWriter(void)" (??0VideoWriter@cv@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl cv::VideoWriter::~VideoWriter(void)" (??1VideoWriter@cv@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __cdecl cv::VideoWriter::open(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int,double,class cv::Size_<int>,bool)" (?open@VideoWriter@cv@@UEAA_NAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@HNV?$Size_@H@2@_N@Z) referenced in function main
```

So I'm thinking I need to enable a non-default feature.  OpenCV was originally installed like this:

```
vcpkg install --triplet x64-windows-static-md opencv4
```

By default, this seems to install `[dnn,jpeg,opengl,png,tiff,webp]`.

I've also tried adding a few more of the optional features, including:

```
vcpkg install --triplet x64-windows-static-md opencv4[core,jpeg,opengl,png,tiff,webp,ffmpeg,openmp]
```

Output:

```
...cut...
The package opencv4:x64-windows-static-md provides CMake targets:

find_package(OpenCV CONFIG REQUIRED)
# Note: 14 target(s) were omitted.
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE quirc opencv_ml libprotobuf opencv_core)
```

I'm using the vcpkg toolchain file when calling cmake to create the project.  And the relevant portion of my `CMakeLists.txt` file contains the following as instructed by vcpkg:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV CONFIG REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ( BEFORE ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
ADD_EXECUTABLE ( mytest main.cpp )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ( mytest PRIVATE quirc opencv_ml libprotobuf opencv_core )
```

Part of the problem is the vcpkg `ports/opencv4/control` file contains probably 20 optional features, and the descriptions are nearly useless.

**My question:**

Anyone know what vcpkg feature is needed to get access to the `cv::VideoWriter` class, or what to look for in the code so I can figure out which optional feature is required?

Comment: The response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25876738/3987854) claims this class is defined in `videoio`, so you might add `opencv_videoio` to your list of linked libraries in CMake. That may work, of course, if vcpkg pulled in that package.

Comment: Something I just discovered: the names of the various link targets is in a file named `OpenCVModules.cmake`.  For example, on my system I found that file at `vcpkg\packages\opencv4_x64-windows-static-md\share\opencv\OpenCVModules.cmake`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @squareskittles commented, the solution is due to some missing names in the `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` line generated by vcpkg.

The solution for me was to changed this line:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ( mytest PRIVATE quirc opencv_ml libprotobuf opencv_core )
```

...to instead look like this:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ( mytest PRIVATE quirc opencv_ml libprotobuf opencv_core opencv_videoio )
```

And in one of my other test apps, I also had to add `opencv_highgui`.  Looks like the "target" lines generated by vcpkg don't contain everything needed.