# OpenCV: cannot compile when using imwrite() function

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, linker, libstdc++

In my simple first OpenCV application I want to save frames got by cam so I am using `imwrite()` as tutorial say. The problem, is that I can't compile because I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"cv::imwrite(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int,  std::allocator<int> > const&)", referenced from:
_main in video-87ad7a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Reading some posts here in SO I have discovered it's a problem about the C++ standard library which is used, so I added the flag `libstdc++` but the following:

```
g++ -stdlib=libstdc++ -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib/ -g -o binary video.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab
```

has not solved the problem. How shall I do?

**UPDATE**
it seems [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816607/opencv-2-3-compiling-issue-undefined-refence-ubuntu-11-10) is the solution. I don't know what was the damned flag I was missing

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like you are missing '-lopencv_imgcodecs' where imwrite() lives.
Refer to OpenCV imgcodecs header file [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d87/imgcodecs_8hpp.html#gsc.tab=0).

Comment: Interesting thing - when I switched to the clang, I started to get that error, even though previously with gcc it worked without problems.